# Javascript - Find Comma Exists In String

Tags: javascript

I need to find if a comma exists in a javascript string so I know whether to do str.split(',') on it or not.

Is this the correct way: `var myVar = str.search(',');` ?

If the value of myVar is greater than 0 (zero) then there is a comma in the string?

I'm just not sure if I've got the parameter right in search()

Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function:

```
if (string.indexOf(',') > -1) { string.split(',') }
```

Comment: +1: `search()` is used for regular expressions. For something like a comma, use `indexOf()`. Also, if the value is greater than *-1* then there is a comma in the string.

Comment: @logic-unit, a quick explanation: your method works and is 100% valid, however this answer is slightly better, since this performs a simple string search, whereas `.search` will convert your comma to a regular expression (and build a state machine etc.) which is every so slightly slower.

Comment: I tried checking for comma using `indexOf()` on the result of values of a multiple select dropdown `result = $(this).val();  alert(selectedValues.indexOf(","));` and it always resulted -1 even when there was comma in result (e.g. when result contained "-1,2"). Doing `result.toString()` before the `.indexOf()` check made it work. However there was no such issue while checking for presence of "-1". Strange...

Comment: @SandeepanNath from where come `selectedValues` ?

Comment: `if (string.includes(',')) {
  console.log('comma found')
}`

Answer (score 13):

Use new functions natively coming from ES6:

```
const text = "Hello, my friend!";
const areThereAnyCommas = text.includes(',');
```

Answer (score 6):

`.search()` is used for regular expressions, making it a bit overkill for this situation.

Instead, you can simply use `indexOf()`:

```
if (str.indexOf(',') != -1) {
    var segments = str.split(',');
}
```

`.indexOf()` returns the position of the *first occurrence* of the specified string, or `-1` if the string is not found.

Answer (score 4):

```
var strs;
if( str.indexOf(',') != -1 ){
    strs = str.split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way to get value.**

```js
 
 let yourString = 'hellow,okey'; 
let stringResult = yourString.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a nice extra info:
If my string was for example: 33  instead of 34,56,43,86,54,37 the was an error in the console like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: .indexOf is not a function
```

because the number 33 was seen as an **number** instead of a **string**. So I needed to convert the number to a string

```
caller = caller.toString();

   var a = [caller]; 
    if (caller.indexOf(',') > -1) { 
        var a = caller.split(',');
    }
```

Comment: Save your time on this 10 years old question. OP already made the assumption we are working on a JavaScript string.